# `conda-build` failing to populate working source directory?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

After updating the *Anaconda* installation on my Windows 11 Home Dell XPS-15 7590 laptop, my previously working `conda build` recipes are failing, all in the same manner:

```
(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ conda build --python=3.9 --numpy=1.23 -c dbanas -c defaults -c conda-forge conda.recipe/enable/
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Adding in variants from config.variant
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from config.variant
Attempting to finalize metadata for enable
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for enable
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
BUILD START: ['enable-5.3.1-py39h2ed9b0f_2.tar.bz2']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\conda-bld\enable_1677067522896\_h_env


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:                1.0-mkl
{snip}

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\conda-bld\enable_1677067522896\_build_env


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    bzip2:          1.0.8-he774522_0
{snip}

Preparing transaction: ...working... done
Verifying transaction: ...working... done
Executing transaction: ...working... WARNING conda.gateways.disk.create:make_menu(237): Environment name starts with underscore '_'. Skipping menu installation.
done
Using legacy MSVC compiler setup.  This will be removed in conda-build 4.0. If this recipe does not use a compiler, this message is safe to ignore.  Otherwise, use {{compiler('<language>')}} jinja2 in requirements/build.
WARNING:conda_build.windows:Using legacy MSVC compiler setup.  This will be removed in conda-build 4.0. If this recipe does not use a compiler, this message is safe to ignore.  Otherwise, use {{compiler('<language>')}} jinja2 in requirements/build.
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.
source tree in: C:\Users\capnf\anaconda3\conda-bld\enable_1677067522896\work
{snip}

(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ l ~/anaconda3/conda-bld/enable_1677067522896/work/
bld.bat
build_env_setup.bat
conda_build.bat
metadata_conda_debug.yaml
work/

(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$ l ~/anaconda3/conda-bld/enable_1677067522896/work/work/

(base)
capnf@DESKTOP-G84ND7C MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PyBERT (master)
$
```

**It appears that `conda-build` is failing to populate its working source directory.**

Is this a known pathology in the latest `conda-build` system?
And, if so, are there any working hypotheses as to how it's being triggered?
Is there a known temporary work-around?

Here's my complete `meta.yaml` file, for reference:

```yaml
{% set name = "enable" %}
{% set version = "5.3.1" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  git_url: https://github.com/enthought/{{name}}.git
  git_rev: {{version}}

build:
  number: 2
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --no-deps --ignore-installed -vv "

requirements:
  build:
    - setuptools
    - git
    - cmake
    - swig
    # - {{compiler('c')}}
    # - {{ compiler('cxx') }}
    # - {{ cdt('xorg-x11-devel') }}  # [linux]
    - vs2019_win-64
  host:
    - fonttools
    - numpy
    - pillow
    - pip
    - pyface >=7.4.2
    - pyparsing
    - python
    - six
    - traitsui
    - Cython
  run:
    - fonttools
    - numpy
    - pillow
    - pyface >=7.4.2
    - pyparsing
    - python
    - six
    - traitsui

test:
  imports:
    - enable
    - enable.drawing
    - enable.gadgets
    - enable.layout
    - enable.null
    - enable.primitives
    # - enable.pyglet_backend
    - enable.qt4
    - enable.savage
    - enable.savage.compliance
    - enable.savage.svg
    - enable.savage.svg.backends
    - enable.savage.svg.backends.kiva
    - enable.savage.svg.backends.null
    - enable.savage.svg.backends.wx
    - enable.savage.svg.css
    - enable.savage.svg.tests
    - enable.savage.svg.tests.css
    - enable.savage.trait_defs
    - enable.savage.trait_defs.ui
    - enable.savage.trait_defs.ui.qt4
    - enable.savage.trait_defs.ui.wx
    - enable.tests
    - enable.tests.primitives
    - enable.tests.qt4
    - enable.tests.tools
    # - enable.tests.tools.apptools
    - enable.tests.wx
    - enable.tools
    - enable.tools.apptools
    - enable.tools.pyface
    - enable.tools.toolbars
    - enable.trait_defs
    - enable.trait_defs.ui
    - enable.trait_defs.ui.qt4
    - enable.trait_defs.ui.wx
    # - enable.vtk_backend
    - enable.wx
    - kiva
    - kiva.agg
    - kiva.agg.tests
    - kiva.fonttools
    - kiva.fonttools.tests
    - kiva.quartz
    - kiva.tests
    - kiva.tests.agg
    - kiva.trait_defs
    - kiva.trait_defs.ui
    - kiva.trait_defs.ui.wx

about:
  home: "https://github.com/enthought/enable/"
  license: "BSD"
  license_family: "BSD"
  license_file: ""
  summary: "low-level drawing and interaction"
  doc_url: ""
  dev_url: ""

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - capn-freako
```